# How to force redrection when url contains question mark in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL :

```
www.example.com/PageName:ArgumentValue1,ArgumentValue2
```

I would like to make a redirection to

```
www.example.com/apex/f?p=alias:PageName:ArgumentValue1,ArgumentValue2
```

I have done so far :

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ ./apex/f?p=alias:$1 [L]
```

The redirection works properly except when an `Argumentvalue` has a question mark.

Is there any way to force such a redirection even if there is a question mark in an argument?

`PageName`, `ArgumentValue1` and `ArgumentValue2` are all dynamic variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `www.example.com/PageName:ArgumentValue1,ArgumentValue2`

Since the *ArgumentValues* are part of the URL-path then any *literal* `?` (question mark) should be URL encoded as `%3F` in the request. Otherwise, the unencoded `?` indicates the start of the query string and effectively splits the URL in two - which is what is happening here.

As a *workaround*, you can do the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^GET /([^\s]+)"
RewriteRule ^[^:]+: apex/f?p=alias:%1 [L]
```